# Problem Adding Clickable Images In VC++

Tags: c++, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am making a **Windows Form Application** in **C++**.I have to show some images on the interface and when the user clicks the image,an even is driven.The problem is that I am unable to find the option to put such even driven images.
Please help me out.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

- You cannot make Windows Form Application in C++.
- You can make win32 Application in C++.
- You can make Windows Form Application in Managed C++, C++/CLI, C#. All of these are CLR languages. Managed C++ and C++/CLI are not same as Standard C++.

By the way, if you want to use CLR language, then why don't you just start learning WPF? It's easy, and is much more advanced than Windows Form.

Comment: Can we make WPF applications using C++?

Comment: WPF application is developed in CLR language, as such C#. And C# is much easier language than C++. You can start learning it anytime; in one week you learn almost all it's features!